# How to set the page of the scrollView in SLNumberPickerView Sample?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am trying to use a modification of the SLNumberPickerView (see here: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/slnumberpickerview) and like to set the page of the scrollView from my ViewController (means from outside) but don't get it to work.

I'm not sure, but I guess the problem is that the `SLNumberPickerView` uses the `_internalPickerView` as the real pickerView.

Has anyone used this sample code before and got an idea on how my method to programmatically set the page of the scrollView should look like?

What I have so far is:

```
- (void)changeScrollViewPositionOf:(UIScrollView*)scrollView to: (float)page{

    if (_isStandIn) { 
        [self changeScrollViewPositionOf:scrollView to:page ]; //this does not seem to work!
    }
    //again, first normalize values, in case we have minus values etc.
    float currentPosition = page - [self.minLimit floatValue];

    // update the scroll view to the appropriate value/page
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * currentPosition;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = scrollView.frame.size;
    //scroll the view to the new page we want to see
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];  
}
```

If I set the page inside my `SLNumberPickerView` it works, but not if I try to call the method from outside/my ViewController which holds the `SLNumberPickerView`.

Any help would be appriciated.